# How to setup VirtualBox with static IP?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, static-ip

Host OS has one nic with 4 static IP address x.x.x.250-x.x.x.254
I have installed Ubuntu as a Guest OS with bridged networking. I would like it to have static ip x.x.x.255

As I mentioned earlier, host os has ip set manually. I set ip manually for guest os (ubuntu server) but it doesn't seem to be able to ping any ip.

Your help is appreciated

Edit: Host OS does not use IP x.x.x.255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.255 is the broadcast address for your network if your subnet mask is 24 bits (255.255.255.0) and cannot be used for a host address.

You'll have to use an IP less than .250 for your VBox instance.

Answer (score 0):

The issues might be lies on the gateway ip you have used in the guest os.

Here is the reference [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4489) to configure the static ip in virtualbox

Comment: If I am not mistaken, gateway should be same on host os and guest os. In my case it is x.x.x.249 and is set on host os and guest os

Comment: You can create an virtual network interface using the first static ip in the host os and Use that created virtual interface ip as the gateway in the guest os. It will surely works.